# how to insert javascript variables to html.Actionlink ? Using signalR

Tags: javascript, variables, signalr, actionlink

i'm doing a school gaming project and i am trying to create a list of players using SignalR and javascript.

this is my code

```
hub.client.printOutPlayerList = function (userName, userID)
    {
        $("#playerlist ul").append("<li>" + '@(Html.ActionLink(userName, "Profile", "Profile", new { id = userID }, null);)' + "</li>");
    }
```

this function is suppose to take in javascript variables userName and userID but the actionlink doesnt seem to recognize userName and userID

what can i do ?

Comment: You can't .  That code runs on the **server**.

Comment: Do you have any idea how i can implement a link to a users profile without actionlink ?

Comment: Either hard-code URL formats in the Javascript, or use placeholders in server-side `Url.Action`, then replace them on the client.  You can also use an open source project that reimplements the routing engine on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
hub.client.printOutPlayerList = function (userName, userID)
{
    var link = '<a href="/Profile/Profile/' + userID + '">' + userName + '</a>';
    $("#playerlist ul").append('<li>' + link + '</li>');
}
```